# Merge Uneven Data Files

Tags: r, csv, merge

I have 5 weeks of measured data in 5 separate CSV files, and am looking for a way to merge them into a single document that makes sense. The issue I'm having is that not all data points are present in each file, my largest has ~20k rows and my smallest has ~2k so there isn't a 1:1 relation. Here's what my data looks like:

```
Keyword               URL     5/12 Rank
activity         site.com             2
activity    site.com/page             1
backup    site.com/backup             4
```

The next file would look something like this:

```
Keyword               URL     5/19 Rank
activity    site.com/page             2
database    site.com/data             3
```

What I'd like to end up with is something like this

```
Keyword               URL     5/12 Rank     5/19 Rank
activity         site.com             2             -
activity    site.com/page             1             2
backup    site.com/backup             4             -
database    site.com/data             -             3
```

My preference would be to do this with R. I *think* [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) will make this a snap, but I've never used it before and I'm just not getting how this comes together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge`:

```
csv1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Keyword               URL     5/12_Rank
activity         site.com             2
activity    site.com/page             1
backup    site.com/backup             4
")

csv2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Keyword               URL     5/19_Rank
activity    site.com/page             2
database    site.com/data             3
")

csv12 <- merge(csv1, csv2, all=TRUE)

#> csv12
#   Keyword             URL X5.12_Rank X5.19_Rank
#1 activity        site.com          2         NA
#2 activity   site.com/page          1          2
#3   backup site.com/backup          4         NA
#4 database   site.com/data         NA          3
```

If you have several tables, you can put them in a `list` and use `Reduce`:

```
csv3 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Keyword               URL     5/42_Rank
activity         site.com             5
html        site.com/data             6
")
L <- list(csv1, csv2, csv3)

Reduce(f=function(x,y)merge(x,y,all=TRUE), L)
```

Result

```
#   Keyword             URL X5.12_Rank X5.19_Rank X5.42_Rank
#1 activity        site.com          2         NA          5
#2 activity   site.com/page          1          2         NA
#3   backup site.com/backup          4         NA         NA
#4 database   site.com/data         NA          3         NA
#5     html   site.com/data         NA         NA          6
```

Comment: You can just use `all = TRUE`, and before you notice it and worry, the OP has a typo in their output specification.

Comment: ...also worth pointing out `Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,all = TRUE),list(csv1,csv2,csv3))` for doing this all at once.

Comment: I'm floored at the simplicity of this. I was making this way more complicated than it needed to be. Thanks for the assist!